# Using Scopes on the Load method not working

Tags: eloquent

Is there a way to abstract this Closure to my MerchantUser model in a way similar to using [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes) on `with()`?

So far I have this which works:

```php
$merchant_user->load(['permissions' => function ($query) use ($merchantId) {
    if ($merchantId) {
        $query->where('merchant_user_permission.merchant_id','=', $merchantId);
    }
}]);
```

---

But I'd like to do something like this:

```php
$merchant_user->loadPermissions($merchantId);
```

In my Model:

```php
public function scopeLoadPermissions($query, $merchantId = null)
{
    return $query->load(['permissions' => function ($q) use ($merchantId) {
        if ($merchantId) {
            $q->where('merchant_user_permission.merchant_id','=', $merchantId);
        }
    }]);
}
```

Which at the moment just returns an error:

> "Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::load does not exist."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case you dont need add scope. Instead if you can add this function in your model

```
public function loadPermissions($merchantId = null)
{
    return $this->load(['permissions' => function ($q) use ($merchantId) {
        if ($merchantId) {
            $q->where('merchant_user_permission.merchant_id','=', $merchantId);
        }
    }]);
}
```

and usage

```
$merchant_user->loadPermissions($merchantId);
```